# jquery-ui dialog won't close in Internet Explorer on Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, internet-explorer, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a div that I'm making into a dialog and then opening it on document ready.
The dialog shows up but doesn't respond to clicking the x to close or to clicking the ok button.

I'm using jquery-ui, and a custom theme created by themeroller: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

The code works in IE if I'm not running it as a Facebook app, it also works as a Facebook app if I use a different browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).

The IE java console shows an error in the jquery-ui code:
SCRIPT 16389: Unspecified error.
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js, line 73 character 5487

Here's the code:

```
    <head>
      <link type="text/css" href="/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function showPopup() {
        $( '#dialog' ).dialog('open');
      }

      $( function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false, show: "blind", hide: "blind", buttons: { "OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } });
      }) ;
      </script>

      </head>
      <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){showPopup();});
      </script> 

      <div id='dialog' style="display: none;" title='title of the dialog'>
      Dialog message
      </div>

      </body>
```

Comment: Stab in the dark - Have you perhaps left some `console.log()` statements in your code somewhere?  IE doesn't like it that much - especially if the debug console is not open.  Also what version of IE would be tremendously helpful... Its not IE 6... I know that much :P

Comment: I'm currently able to reproduce this with IE9.  I have seen it with IE8 also, but don't have that system setup to reproduce it.  Also, I am able to reproduce it on an isolated page with no other code.

Answer (score 2):

jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js has an issue inside of an IE9 IFRAME where it doesn't set the `.focus` properly, most likely trying to set the focus to the body element of the page rather than the body tag of the IFRAME itself.  I got around the issue by setting an id to the IFRAME body tag.

```
body id="bodyTag"
```

Then inside your `document.ready` function, set the focus to the IFRAME body tag:

```
$("#bodyTag").focus();
```